# Is it possible to get user's username trying to access a particular map service in both ArcGIS Online and Enterprise Portal?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-enterprise

I am trying to get list of users who are accessing a map service or web map. Using ArcGIS Online and Portal 10.8.1
In the usage tab of the content it shows how many times map is access and not who accessed.
I tried to get the REST URL for the same but wasn't successful.

Comment: Usage of Registered Apps by Org Members..
similar to one which is shown in AGOL >status >apps>Usage of Registered Apps by Org Members..

how do we extract this info